# How to overlay dynamic ul on another div in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on javascript and i am doing dynamic ul using api and getting parsed data on ul.

But having an issue is that  i want to overlay it on another div. So that it didn't get more space. I want to overlap it on another div id.

HTML

```
<div id="oe_overlay">
    <input type="text" 
            data-type="search" 
            placeholder="Search here..." 
            name="order_booking_product" 
            id="order_booking_product" 
            data-mini="true" onkeyup="searchboxorder()">
    <ul class="order_product" 
        data-role="listview" 
        id="order_product" data-insert="true"  
        data-
        data-theme="a">
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#oe_overlay
{
    background:#000;
    opacity:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

ul.order_product
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately we are not mind reader ... post your code and give us more details

Comment: Friend!  post your code with some more details.

Answer (score 0):

When you change your ul from position:relative to position:absolute it should do the trick. If I understood you right.

```
ul.order_product
{
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```